# Android Cannot resolve Xml.newSerializer()

Tags: java, android, xml

I am implementing XmlSerializer according to this [Guide](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-android/#N10210), but I keep getting

> Error:(40, 51) error: cannot find symbol class newSerializer

on compilation. Moreover, in class Xml.java I have noticed two unresolved symbols for:

```
import org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader;
import org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser;
```

How to solve this problem? Is it related to project settings?

**My code**

```
package com.example.XmlFiles;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Xml;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class XmlFileParser {

private final static String FILE_NAME = "settings.xml";

static class xmlTags {
    final String mainHeader = "Settings";
    final String[] sharingMethodHeaders = { "SmsSharing", "EmailSharing" };
    final String[] pickersHeaders = { "TimePicker", "DatePicker" };
    final String[] timePickerHeaders = { "Hours", "Minutes" };
    final int[] timePickerValues = { 0, 0 };
    final String[] datePickerHeader = { "Years", "Months", "Days" };
    final int[] datePickerValues = { 0, 0, 0 };
}

/**
 * Creates xml file for storing sharing settings
 * @param context Activity context
 */
public void createSettingsFile(Context context, String path)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    File xmlFile = new File(path + FILE_NAME);
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(xmlFile);
    if (!xmlFile.exists()) {
        try {
            xmlTags tags = new xmlTags();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new Xml.newSerializer();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            serializer.setOutput(writer);
            serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
            serializer.startTag("", tags.mainHeader);
            for (int i = 0; i < tags.sharingMethodHeaders.length; i++) {
                serializer.startTag("", tags.sharingMethodHeaders[i]);
                for (int j = 0; j < tags.pickersHeaders.length; j++) {
                    serializer.startTag("", tags.pickersHeaders[j]);
                    String[] headerTmp;
                    int[] valuesTmp;
                    switch (j) {
                        default:
                            headerTmp = tags.timePickerHeaders;
                            valuesTmp = tags.timePickerValues;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            headerTmp = tags.datePickerHeader;
                            valuesTmp = tags.datePickerValues;
                            break;
                    }
                    for (int k = 0; k < headerTmp.length; k++)
                    {
                        serializer.startTag("", headerTmp[k]);
                        serializer.text(Integer.toString(valuesTmp[k]));
                        serializer.endTag(headerTmp[k], null);
                    }
                    serializer.endTag(tags.pickersHeaders[j], null);
                }
                serializer.endTag(tags.sharingMethodHeaders[i], null);
            }
            serializer.endTag(tags.mainHeader, null);
            serializer.endDocument();
            file.write(serializer.toString().getBytes());
        } finally {
            file.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: the method is static. you don't need the `new` operator. Change `XmlSerializer serializer = new Xml.newSerializer();` with `XmlSerializer serializer =  Xml.newSerializer();`

Comment: @Blackbelt Thanks, this solved my problem. I did not noticed it earlier.